# Why deploying custom master page module feature using VS only update 1 site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have many site collections and a custom master page module feature created using VS...

Now when I deploy this visual studio solution using to a site collection 1, it updates the master page in master page list and when I deploy the wsp using this script,

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity MasterPage.wsp –LiteralPath "C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\MasterPage.wsp" –GacDeployment
```

it doesn't not update master page in any of site collection.

**Problem**

- Why script doesn't updates master page in all site collections master page library
- Why it only updates 1 site collection master page library when deployed using visual studio

Please note I am using custom web templates...

All I want to do is update master page in a single go for ALL existing site collections.

***Feature is site scoped.***

Comment: You are just updating the solution..not activating the feature associated with it

Comment: @SharepointExpert feature is already activated and I updating solution not adding it, so I am not sure what else I need to do :)

Comment: I think it's related to ghosting etc... but I am not sure

Comment: Did you try retract and deploy solution instead of just update?